# Parsing Mod-Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get two parameters with mod-rewrite. I tried to split them with "-" but unfortunately it returns last word as second parameter.

/ders/ilkogretim-matematik
/ders/ilkogretim-fen-ve-teknoloji

should be the URLs, "ilkogretim" will be the first parameter and the rest of it will be the second parameter. (After first "-")

My rules as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^ders/(.*)-(.*)/?$  /ogretmenler.php?sinif=$1&ders=$2  [QSA,L]
```

I hope I could explain the problem..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.` is only capturing a single character - you need a quantifier on there.
I've also made the first group capture any character except `-`:

```
ders/([^-]+)-(.*)/?$ /ogretmenler.php?sinif=$1&ders=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the single dots `(.)-(.)` will only match a single character. You probably want something like

```
^/ders/([^-]*)-(.*)/?$
```

The first group will match zero or more non `-` characters, followed by the single `-` and then the 2nd group will match zero or more of any character (you could restrict this more if desired).